# TabularX - with rowcolor - Unwanted gap between columns

Tags: tables, spacing, rowcolor

I have a problem with the rowcolor of the tabularx.
I have a column with dimensions where I want all the 'x' chars centered.

I thought of two solutions. One with the  c@{ x } definition in the table columns. (i know this cant be filled with rowcolor, but is it exactly what I wanted.

The other one is to define for each x a column.. but then the spacing is not nice.. 
Is there an option to giva de c@{ x } a background color for each row?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{tabelzwart}{cmyk}{.0,.0,.0,1}
\definecolor{tabelgrijs}{cmyk}{.0,.0,.0,.15}
\definecolor{Akzent}{rgb}{0.6627, 0.63529, 0.55294} %akzentfarbe
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand\colourpadding[1]{\addlinespace[-1pt]\arrayrulecolor{#1}\midrule[6pt]\arrayrulecolor{black}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
                    L{26mm}
                    r@{\extracolsep{\fill} \ x \ }
                    c@{ \ x \ }
                    l
                    C{23mm}
                    C{19mm}
                    C{19mm}
                 }
\rowcolor{tabelzwart}
  \textcolor{white}{Article \newline code} &
  \multicolumn{3}{p{45mm}}{\cellcolor{tabelzwart}\textcolor{white}{Dimension}} &
  \textcolor{white}{QA} &
  \textcolor{white}{Per bag} &
  \textcolor{white}{Per Box} \\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs}80100 & 17.5 & 19.1   & 17.5  & {G} & 10 & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}80100 & 17.5 & 19.1   & 17.5  & {G} & 10 & 100\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs}22333 & 11.8 & 12.7   & 29.3  & {KWW} & 10 & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}70100 & 326.632  &  5.6   & 35.9  & {G K} & 190 & 100\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs}70100 & 36.6  &  5.6   & 35.9  & {G K} & 190 & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}70100 & 6.6  &  53.63   & 35.9  & {G / K} & 9 & 10\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs}70100 & 6.6  &  53.6   & 35.9  & {G} & 190 & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}70100 & 6.6  &  5.6   & 35.9  & {G} & 1903 & 100\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs}70100 & 6.6  &  53.6   & 35.9  & {G} & 190 & 100\\
\end{tabular}
\\
\\
\\
{x} in other columns
\\
\\
\\
\begin{tabular}{
                    L{26mm}
                    r
                    |C{5mm}
                    c
                    |C{5mm}
                    l
                    C{23mm}
                    C{19mm}
                    C{19mm}
                 }
  {Article \newline number} &
  1 &
  2 &
  3 &
  4 &
  5 &  
  {QA} &
  {bag} &
  {Box} \\
80100 & 17.5 & {x} & 19.1 & {x}  & 17.5  & {G} & 10 & 100\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks.

Comment: What do you try to achieve exactly? It is not clear to me. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I've added some more information with screenshots in a post bellow. Hopefully, this is clearer

Comment: Just another question: the x actually means `times (×)`?

Comment: No the x is just a divider for a dimension. (lika a squar of 10inch x 10inch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use separate columns for the `x`, and manipulate spacing using `\tabcolsep`. I find the spacing adequate, but the problem is different numbers of figures behind the decimal point:

**Example 1 – tabcolsep**

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx, }
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tabelzwart}{cmyk}{.0,.0,.0,1}
\definecolor{tabelgrijs}{cmyk}{.0,.0,.0,.15}
\definecolor{Akzent}{rgb}{0.6627, 0.63529, 0.55294} %akzentfarbe
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand\colourpadding[1]{\addlinespace[-1pt]\arrayrulecolor{#1}\midrule[6pt]\arrayrulecolor{black}}

\begin{document}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.25em}
\begin{tabular}{
                    L{26mm}
                    r
                    c
                    c
                    c
                    l
                    C{23mm}
                    C{19mm}
                    C{19mm}
                 }
\rowcolor{tabelzwart}
  \textcolor{white}{Article \newline code} &
  \multicolumn{5}{p{50mm}}{\cellcolor{tabelzwart}\textcolor{white}{Dimension}} &
  \textcolor{white}{QA}      &
  \textcolor{white}{Per bag} &
  \textcolor{white}{Per Box} \\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 80100 & 17.5    & x & 19.1  & x & 17.5  & {G}    & 10  & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}      80100 & 17.5    & x & 19.1  & x & 17.5  & {G}    & 10  & 100\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 22333 & 11.8    & x & 12.7  & x & 29.3  & {KWW}  & 10  & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}      70100 & 326.632 & x &  5.6  & x & 35.9  & {G K}  & 190 & 100\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 70100 & 36.6    & x &  5.6  & x & 35.9 & {G K}   & 190 & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}      70100 & 6.6     & x & 53.63 & x & 35.9 & {G / K} & 9   & 10\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 70100 & 6.6     & x & 53.6  & x & 35.9 & {G}     & 190 & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}      70100 & 6.6     & x & 5.6   & x & 35.9 & {G}     & 1903 & 100\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 70100 & 6.6     & x & 53.6  & x & 35.9 & {G}     & 190 & 100\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) and `tabcolsep`**

[image]

A better solution is to set the the three columns with decimal point as `D`-columns, using the package [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn). I have also set the two `\times`-columns as D-columns, giving correct mathematical symbol and nice spacing.

I have fine tuned the column spacing using `\tabolsep` and reduced the width of the `multicolumn` in the heading to 41 mm.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx, dcolumn}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tabelzwart}{cmyk}{.0,.0,.0,1}
\definecolor{tabelgrijs}{cmyk}{.0,.0,.0,.15}
\definecolor{Akzent}{rgb}{0.6627, 0.63529, 0.55294} %akzentfarbe
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand\colourpadding[1]{\addlinespace[-1pt]\arrayrulecolor{#1}\midrule[6pt]\arrayrulecolor{black}}

\begin{document}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.1em}
\begin{tabular}{
                    L{26mm}
                    D{.}{.}{3.3}
                    D{x}{\times}{1}
                    D{.}{.}{2.2}
                    D{x}{\times}{1}
                    D{.}{.}{2.1}
                    C{23mm}
                    C{19mm}
                    C{19mm}
                 }
\rowcolor{tabelzwart}
  \textcolor{white}{Article \newline code} &
  \multicolumn{5}{p{41mm}}{\cellcolor{tabelzwart}\textcolor{white}{Dimension}} &
  \textcolor{white}{QA}      &
  \textcolor{white}{Per bag} &
  \textcolor{white}{Per Box} \\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 80100 & 17.5    & x & 19.1  & x & 17.5 & {G}    & 10 & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}      80100 & 17.5    & x & 19.1  & x & 17.5 & {G}    & 10   & 100\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 22333 & 11.8    & x & 12.7  & x & 29.3 & {KWW}   & 10  & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}      70100 & 326.632 & x &  5.6  & x & 35.9 & {G K}   & 190 & 100\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 70100 & 36.6    & x &  5.6  & x & 35.9 & {G K}   & 190 & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}      70100 & 6.6     & x & 53.63 & x & 35.9 & {G / K} &   9 & 10\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 70100 & 6.6     & x & 53.6  & x & 35.9 & {G}     & 190 & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}      70100 & 6.6     & x & 5.6   & x & 35.9 & {G}     & 1903 & 100\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 70100 & 6.6     & x & 53.6 &x  & 35.9  & {G}     & 190  & 100\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Example 3 – [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), [dcolumns](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) and `\tabcolsep`**

Still not satisfied? Set the two last rows as right aligned X-columns. Better spacing and fewer overfull `hboxes`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx, dcolumn}
\usepackage[table, usenames]{xcolor}  % use xcolor with option instead of color
\definecolor{tabelzwart}{cmyk}{.0,.0,.0,1}
\definecolor{tabelgrijs}{cmyk}{.0,.0,.0,.15}
\definecolor{Akzent}{rgb}{0.6627, 0.63529, 0.55294} %akzentfarbe
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\colourpadding[1]{\addlinespace[-1pt]\arrayrulecolor{#1}\midrule[6pt]\arrayrulecolor{black}}

\begin{document}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.1em}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
                    L{26mm}
                    D{.}{.}{3.3}
                    D{x}{\times}{1}
                    D{.}{.}{2.2}
                    D{x}{\times}{1}
                    D{.}{.}{2.1}
                    C{23mm}
                    R
                    R
                 }
\rowcolor{tabelzwart}
  \textcolor{white}{Article\linebreak code} &
  \multicolumn{5}{p{41mm}}{\cellcolor{tabelzwart}\textcolor{white}{~~\linebreak Dimension}} &
  \textcolor{white}{~~\linebreak QA} &
  \textcolor{white}{Per\linebreak bag} &
  \textcolor{white}{Per\linebreak Box} \\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 80100 & 17.5    & x & 19.1  & x & 17.5 & {G}    & 10 & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}      80100 & 17.5    & x & 19.1  & x & 17.5 & {G}    & 10   & 100\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 22333 & 11.8    & x & 12.7  & x & 29.3 & {KWW}   & 10  & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}      70100 & 326.632 & x &  5.6  & x & 35.9 & {G K}   & 190 & 100\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 70100 & 36.6    & x &  5.6  & x & 35.9 & {G K}   & 190 & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}      70100 & 6.6     & x & 53.63 & x & 35.9 & {G / K} &   9 & 10\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 70100 & 6.6     & x & 53.6  & x & 35.9 & {G}     & 190 & 100\\
\rowcolor{white}      70100 & 6.6     & x & 5.6   & x & 35.9 & {G}     & 1903 & 100\\
\rowcolor{tabelgrijs} 70100 & 6.6     & x & 53.6 &x  & 35.9  & {G}     & 190  & 100\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: tex hero!!! Tnx a lot.

Comment: Is it also possible to left allign the last column of the dimensions?

i read the dcolumn pdf [link](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/table/dcolumn.pdf) but the -1 doesnt work for the last dimension.

Comment: align to the left i mean :)  so the numbers in the last column of the dimensions are next to the x on the left. When i add a empty column after the last dimension, the -1 works.. so i have a work arround

Comment: @ErikB I am not sure if I understand what you are after. Since the last column in the dimension all have the same number of digits, it _is_ left aligned, even if it centred at the full stop. If you want the last column closer to the `x`-signe, you can cheat and use `D{.}{.}{1.1}`. In my MWE, `D{.}{.}{-1}` works, ut give the same result as `D{.}{.}{2.1}`, which is as documented at page 1.

Comment: @ErikB The following header gives a very tight fit: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
                    L{26mm}
                    D{.}{.}{-1}
                    D{x}{\times}{0.0}
                    D{.}{.}{2.2}
                    D{x}{\times}{0.0}
                    D{.}{.}{1.1}
                    C{23mm}
                    R
                    R
                 }`

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabularX}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.0 of 2021-08-10), you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{tabelzwart}{cmyk}{.0,.0,.0,1}
\definecolor{tabelgrijs}{cmyk}{.0,.0,.0,.15}
\definecolor{Akzent}{rgb}{0.6627, 0.63529, 0.55294}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{X[l]r@{ \ $\times$ \ }c@{ \ $\times$ \ }lX[c]X[r]X[r]}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{2}{tabelgrijs}{white}
  \rowcolor{tabelzwart}{1}
\Body
  \RowStyle[color=white]{\sffamily}
  Article code & 
  \Block{1-3}{Dimension} &&&
  QA &
  Per Bag &
  Per Box \\
80100 & 17.5 & 19.1   & 17.5  & G & 10 & 100\\
80100 & 17.5 & 19.1   & 17.5  & G & 10 & 100\\
22333 & 11.8 & 12.7   & 29.3  & KWW & 10 & 100\\
70100 & 326.632  &  5.6   & 35.9  & G K & 190 & 100\\
70100 & 36.6  &  5.6   & 35.9  & G K & 190 & 100\\
70100 & 6.6  &  53.63   & 35.9  & G / K & 9 & 10\\
70100 & 6.6  &  53.6   & 35.9  & G & 190 & 100\\
70100 & 6.6  &  5.6   & 35.9  & G & 1903 & 100\\
70100 & 6.6  &  53.6   & 35.9  & G & 190 & 100\\
\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]